# How to retrieve api xml file from server

Tags: api, ip, whitelist

A company gave me an API feed. I need to retrieve an xml file from the feed. They require that the IP that makes the call is whitelisted. My personal IP changes all the time, so I had my server's IP whitelisted. Now how can I retrieve the xml file??

I tried with this code:

```
<?php
$xml = file_get_contents('https://xxxxxx.com/site/API2?.....);
print $xml;
?>
```

However with this code it still "user has accessed the report from an unauthorized ip address' like if I would just enter the url in my browser and access it from my non-whitelisted IP.

So how can I retrieve the xml file with my server's IP ??

Answer (score 0):

Does this error also occur when white listing your personal IP and retrieving the XML via your browser?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that the IP the server is requesting the API from is different than the whitelisted one. You could try using that code on a service that shows your IP address, and request the API provider to whitelist that IP.